# Outlook not starts without /safe swich

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I was trying to start outlook 2010 in normal mode, but just icon in taskbar is visible. I tried to start with `/safe` prefix. Outlook started normaly without problems. Then I have removed or disabled all plugins one by one each time restarting outlook in normal mode. Each time outlook was not started correctly. How to solve this problem?

Comment: [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)

Comment: Your Outlook seems corrupted. You may run the setup file of MS Office 2010 and choose the "Repair" option.

Answer (score 0):

Recovery Outlook command:

- ```
  Outlook /cleanfreebusy
  ```
- ```
  Outlook /cleanreminders
  ```
- ```
  Outlook /cleanfinders
  ```
- ```
  Outlook /resetnavpane
  ```

Comment: in all ceses outlook just starts in "invisible" mode

Comment: @vico These actions have helped in various cases of refusal to start Outlook in different enterprises and domains. Possible will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It may just happen to be that outlook crashed but remains in memory, causing it to switch to the crashed version.

To be sure: close outlook, word and any other office application, then go to the taskmanager, processes tab, and kill any OUTLOOK.exe process that remains. Then start outlook normally. Also check to see if WORD.exe is open and kill those too. (word can be used by outlook)

If that doesn't do it, outlook may have become corrupted and you may need to repair office.

To do this, go to control panel, Software (or add, remove programs, or programs, featurs, depending on which OS you use) and choose modify/uninstall on outlook. From the uninstall wizard, choose repair.